# Finding the probability of an event using set theory

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Given: $P(A \cup B) = 0.7$, $P(A \cup B') = 0.9$,

Find $P(A)$.

I feel like the answer has something to do with the property that 
$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$ and $P(A \cup B') = P(A) + P(B') - P(AB')$, but I don't know how to get rid of $B$ and $B'$ using the properties. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  Try adding $P(A\cup B)$ and $P(A\cup B')$ and see what cancels.

Remember in particular the law of total probability: $Pr(X\cap Y)+Pr(X\cap Y') = Pr(X)$

$0.7 + 0.9 = Pr(A\cup B) + Pr(A\cup B') = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B) + Pr(A)+Pr(B')-Pr(A\cap B')$

> $ = 2Pr(A) + \left(Pr(B)+Pr(B')\right) - \left(Pr(A\cap B) + Pr(A\cap B')\right)$

$~$

> $ = 2Pr(A) + 1 - Pr(A) = Pr(A)+1$

$~$

> so, $Pr(A) = 1.6 - 1 = 0.6$

Comment: thank you, I'll try this

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply. I attempted to solve this questions again with your hint and I got further than last time I think. however, I'm still stuck with the B and B'. if you could send another hint or something that'd be appreciated @jmoravitz

Comment: @DonaldDevy $Pr(B)+Pr(B') = 1$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you get this equation but it does get me the correct answer, thanks

Comment: $Pr(A') = 1-Pr(A)$ so adding $Pr(A)$ to both sides that is $Pr(A)+Pr(A')=1$.  This is a consequence of law of total probability as well, letting $\Omega$ be the sample space that is $Pr(A\cap \Omega) + Pr(A'\cap \Omega)  = Pr(\Omega) = 1$

Answer (score 0):

P(A u B) + P(A u B') = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) + P(A) + P(B') - P(AB')

0.7 + 0.9 = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB) + P(A) + P(B') - P(AB')

1.6 = 2P(A) + P(B) + P(B') - [P(AB) + P(AB')]

1.6 = 2P(A) + P(B) +P(B') - P(A)                                                   [law of total probability]

1.6 = P(A) +P(B) + P(B')

1.6 = P(A) + 1                                                                                  [P(B) + P{B') = 1]

P(A) = 0.6

Comment: Use $P(B)+P(B^\complement)=1$ where $B^\complement$ denotes the complement of $B$.

Comment: b' is the compliment of b?

Comment: By definition $P(A^\complement)=1-P(A)$ for any event $A$, then add $P(A)$ to both sides.